# How to skip one ancestor element when event bubbling?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have `parent -> child -> sub child`, and I want to add a click event listener to all three elements. I am trying to achieve this: when `sub child` is clicked, I want to skip the `child` listener but still want to execute the `parent` listeners. Is there any way to achieve this?

```js
function parentClick() {
 alert('parent click');
}


function childClick() {
 alert('childClick');
}

function subChildClick() {
 alert('subChildClick');
}
```

```css
.parent {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}

.child {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: red;
 padding: 20px;
}

.sub-child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" onClick="parentClick()">
 parent
  <div class="child" onClick="childClick()">
     child
    <div class="sub-child" onClick="subChildClick()">sub child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks.

Comment: I guess `angular` and `reactjs` has nothing to do with your question

Comment: No direct way. The `stopPropagation` method exists - but that will stop _all_ propagation from that point on, so if you called it in your sub-child handler, it would prevent _all_ further bubbling up of the event. Your child callback function should check what the original event target was - and then simply _do nothing_, if it wasn't the child itself.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean by no direct way? Don't like [my suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75986246/227299)?

Comment: Your suggestions implement exactly what I said. And no, I do not consider that "direct" - the child listener does not get "skipped", but it _actively_ informs itself about the situation, and then decides to simply _do_ nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (without requiring [inelegant flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75986185/227299)) is to check in the child click handler if the target of the click is the sub child.

### Using [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

This is a better solution than using `matches` since you don't need to find a good selector that will only apply to `.sub-child`.

```js
function parentClick() {
  alert('parent click');
}


function childClick(e, el) {
  // The extra check is because "A node is contained inside itself".
  // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains
  if (el.contains(e.target) && el !== e.target) {
     return;
  }
  alert('childClick');

}

function subChildClick() {
  alert('subChildClick');
}
```

```css
div { padding: 20px }
.parent { background-color: green }
.child { background-color: yellow }
.sub-child { background-color: red }
```

```html
<div class="parent" onClick="parentClick(event)">
  parent
  <div class="child" onClick="childClick(event, this)">
    child
    <div class="sub-child" onClick="subChildClick(event)">sub child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

```js
function parentClick() {
  alert('parent click');
}


function childClick(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches(".sub-child")) {
    alert('childClick');
  }
}

function subChildClick() {
  alert('subChildClick');
}
```

```css
div { padding: 20px }
.parent { background-color: green }
.child { background-color: yellow }
.sub-child { background-color: red }
```

```html
<div class="parent" onClick="parentClick(event)">
  parent
  <div class="child" onClick="childClick(event)">
    child
    <div class="sub-child" onClick="subChildClick(event)">sub child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selectors in the matches methods in the switch-case doesn't need to be this specific since you're only listening on events in the parent.

This way you only have one event listener and the code is relatively understandable

```js
document.querySelector(".btn.parent").addEventListener("click", ($event) => {
    if ($event.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
        switch (true) {
            case $event.target.matches(".btn.child"):
                alert("child click");
                break;
            case $event.target.matches(".btn.sub-child"):
                alert("subchild click");
                break;
        }
        alert("parent click");
    }
});
```

```css
.parent {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}

.child {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: red;
 padding: 20px;
}

.sub-child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent btn">
    parent
    <div class="child btn">
        child
        <div class="sub-child btn">sub child</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also use onClick

```js
const parentClick = ($event) => {
    if ($event.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
        switch (true) {
            case $event.target.matches(".btn.child"):
                alert("child click");
                break;
            case $event.target.matches(".btn.sub-child"):
                alert("subchild click");
                break;
        }
        alert("parent click");
    }
};
```

```css
.parent {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}

.child {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: yellow;
 color: red;
 padding: 20px;
}

.sub-child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent btn" onClick="parentClick(event)">
    parent
    <div class="child btn">
        child
        <div class="sub-child btn">sub child</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This diverges quite a bit from the original question's code.

Answer (score 0):

Add flag that will be checked in `childClick`:

```
let flag = false;

function subChildClick() {
    flag = true;
}

function childClick() {
    if (!flag) {
        doSomeStuff();
    }

    flag = false;
}
```